# Using css position to position a dynamically loaded search results box

Tags: css, position

Here's how it looks like in my machine:

[image]

If you [visit the site](http://oracleoflegends.com/Tome/Champions) and search for something I'm sure you will see this box misaligned because your monitor/resolution might be different than mine.

My question is, how can I position this so it's always under the search box regardless of the width of the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `#mini-search-wrapper`. You can then align the search-results based on the position of the `#mini-search-wrapper`-element.

`position: absolute` is bound to the next parent element with a `position: relative` defined. In this case you did not define a relative position on an element so it's bound to the document-root, which is the html-element.

`position: fixed` is always bound to the document-root.

The default `position` in a browser is `static`.

I hope this helps you understanding how the `position`-property works in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solved the position glitch, however the search results aren't being displayed. They're being hidden inside the container of `mini-search-wrapper` as if it were set to `overflow:hidden;`. If I *manually* give `mini-search-wrapper` a height, the search results are displayed, however the content is pushed downwards to give room for the results. I'd like the results to just hover over any content below it.

Comment: It seems the **parent** of `mini-search-wrapper` had `overflow:hidden` - let me do some testing.

Comment: Yes, that was the additional issue. Thanks, your post helped me understand CSS positions. (Finally!)